# How to get user default email address in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, email

Is there any way by which i can get current users email address of ios device.

i need all the default email address or email address of associated google account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not get the email address configured in the Mail app since it's considered breach of privacy. 
You can however use the `MFMailComposeViewController` which will prompt the user to send email using their email address.

Comment: I will add that if you are new to iOS development, you have to understand that apps are strictly sandboxed and you can forget any feature that would require some kind of "root" access or that tries to get any "private" information from iOS. All features that affect privacy will use very specific APIs form iOS that will prompt the user for confirmation (i.e location, access to contacts, camera...).